# Refresh materialized view in teiid

Tags: sql, view, materialized-views, teiid

I have created a teiid vdb with sql server data source. 
The view model contains a materialized view, need to know how to refresh the materialized view manually(like daily or hourly basis) or automatically? Is there any sql command to trigger the refresh action?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, teiid supports both on-demand and periodic refresh of materialized views:

- use the `SYSADMIN.refreshMatView` procedure to refresh the view manually
- use the `/*+ cache(ttl:<milliseconds>) */` cache hint in the view transformation to enable periodic updates

See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/teiid810final/Internal+Materialization for more information.

Comment: I have tried below SP call in my kettle transformation, Execute sql script step.


`CALL SYSADMIN.refreshMatViewRow('PDB_MatVw',false);`

"PDB_MatVw - name of my view model."
but it shows 'TEIID30351 Group 'PDB_MatVw' not found'
tried using schema.PDB_MatVw and got the same error.

Comment: I think you are mixing two things: `refreshMatViewRow` is described in the "Updatable" section in the docs I linked, and takes the name of the table and the _key_ of the row to refresh. `refreshMatView` is described in the "Using System Procedure" section and takes the name of the table and _a boolean_ indicating whether to invalidate the cache.Could you try `CALL SYSADMIN.refreshMatView('PDB_MatVw',false);` ?

Comment: Hi Asmigala, I have tried as mentioned and it works perfectly. but out of curiosity, how to use 'TTL Snapshot Refresh'. dont know whether its a callable statement or do i need to add the `+ cache(ttl:3600000)` to my view query?